# sending arabic data with query string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to send arabic keywords with query string and by matching this string I am getting some data from the database .I am appending the arabic word to the url but but It is not returning any data. May be there is some problem with the string encoding . Its working fine with the English text .Do anybody know how to send the arabic keyword with the query string ?(Right now I am not applying any encoding to the arabic keyword which I am sending in the query string  )

Comment: are you using sqlite on the device? how do you initially store the arabic values?

Comment: No ,I am not using sqlite . I am fetching data from the server . Thats why I am using query string

Comment: how do you send the query string to the server? if you post some code it will be easier

Comment: I am not doing anything special in the code just appending my arabic data like : www.testServer.com/search&title = arabictext

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape your query string with:

```
query_str = [query_str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: So do i need to do any thing different at the server side side for decoding that again ?

Comment: yes it is but then I need to decode this at server side ? isn't it ?

Comment: Yes you have to unescape your query string at the server side. This is very common in webapps/apis.

Comment: Yes i will try that tommorow. But do have any sample how should it be unescape at server side?

Comment: You can find many examples on many programming languages around the web. Search for unescape/unquote strings

Comment: Di you find your way around this?